# Sabre web services and TAs

Tags: c#, sabre

How can you count (or find) the number of sabre TAs your application is using while consuming sabre web services? (Not using the newer REST apis, using the older web services)

Answer (score 1):

You should keep track of the sessions yourself. However Sabre told me the session limit is not enforced strictly and its more to measure their capacity.

If you should go over constantly they will get into contact with you. However watch you Look to book quota as this is usually the measure to determine your bill at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

There is no service to obtain the number of sessions in use. Best approach is to build your own session management and keep track of opened vs closed sessions.

Comment: I know exactly how many sessions I've opened/closed throughout the lifespan of my application but it does not track 1 to 1 with sabre TAs - and that's the info that I can't find an answer to....